# doxygen markdown fails to parse fenced code block

Tags: markdown, doxygen

Doxygen fails to parse [fenced code blocks](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_fenced) in a markdown file. Here's my snippet:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~{.cpp}
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This appears in the output as plaintext.

> ```
> int main() { printf("Hello World"); } ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks trivial in hindsight, but I spent a lot of time debugging it, so thought I should share it with the community. The problem was that the number of tildes `~` at the start and end of the fenced block should be equal.

Minimum 3 tildes are required to mark a fenced block, but to make the fenced block more easily visible, I like extending them to the complete line. I had originally copy-pasted the starting line at the end, but I then removed a few `~`s to make room for the `{.cpp}`.

Answer (score -1):

```
~~~c
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
}
~~~
```

At the beginning and the end of the same number of (~).
You can like it more beutiful code block.